# Are there other types of blocking in queueing networks beyond Type I?

Tags: queueing

The [Ciw documentation states](https://ciw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Background/mechanisms.html#blocking-mechanism)

> In Ciw, Type I blocking (blocking after service) is implemented for restricted networks.
>
> After service, a customer’s next destination is sampled from the transition matrix. If there is space at the destination node, that customer will join the queue there. Else if the destination node’s queueing capacity is full, then that customer will be blocked. That customer remains at that node, with its server, until space becomes available at the destination. This means the server that was serving that customer remains attached to that customer, being unable to serve anyone else until that customer is unblocked.
>
> At the time of blockage, information about this customer is added to the destination node’s blocked_queue, a virtual queue containing information about all the customers blocked to that node, and the order in which they became blocked. Thus, the sequence of unblockages happen in the order which customers were blocked.
>
> Circular blockages can lead to [deadlock](https://ciw.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Guides/deadlock.html#detect-deadlock).

So if there is a Type I blocking I imagine there would also be a Type II and perhaps more.

What other blocking mechanisms are there?

Answer (score 0):

Horst Hermann Von brand described three mechanisms of blocking in [*Queueing Networks With Blocking* (1987)](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwj3qKLKpd2CAxU4JzQIHRAYCiQQFnoECBEQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Frepository.lsu.edu%2Fcgi%2Fviewcontent.cgi%3Farticle%3D5479%26context%3Dgradschool_disstheses&usg=AOvVaw2p4gL74Pa49XnXbv1bN_WF&opi=89978449):

> 2.1 **The Transfer Blocking Policy**
> Once a job finishes service at station i, it determines the station to which it will go next
> Assume this is station j . If station j is full, the job remains in the server of station i, blocking it to other jobs. Once there is room in station j , the job leaves station i to join the queue of station j . The next job in the queue of station i (if any) can enter the server and begin service.

> 2.2 **The Service Blocking Policy** Before a job enters the server of service station i, it determines (according to the routing probabilities
> Pij) to which station j it will go once its service at station i is finished. If station j has space
> for this job, the job is allowed to start service at station i . Otherwise, the job is blocked in station i
> without being served, and no other job can be served in the meantime at station i .

> 2.3 **The Rejection Blocking Policy** After finishing a round of service at station i, a job determines to which station j it will go next.
> Depending on the state of the destination station j , the job might be accepted or rejected there. We
> call the state-dependent probability that a new job is accepted the blocking function of the destination
> station. If the job is rejected, it returns to station i to get another round of service independently drawn
> from its service requirement distribution at station i (not the same service requirement). The above
> process is repeated when the new round of service is finished.

---

The lead Ciw developer, Geraint Palmer, [enumerated](https://github.com/CiwPython/Ciw/issues/232#issuecomment-1862992288) these different types:

> Yes, my go-to reference is: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0167637786900672
>
> Type 1: customers are blocked after finishing service.
>
> Type 2: customers are blocked before starting service (that is, service only starts once we know they can move on). I think this is difficult to generalise in networks, where the way ahead might get filled up during the service time.
>
> Type 3: customers repeat their service until the path ahead is clear.